# dataTable addClass('selected') not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a function to add a new row to a table. I then want to change the selected row of the table to the new row added. So I remove the selected class from the currently selected row.

```
$('#regressionListTable tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

I add the row...

```
var rowAdded = analysisTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false);
```

And then I add the 'selected' class to this added row.

```
$(rowAdded).addClass('selected');
```

But for some reason the last step doesn't work and no row on my table is highlighted after I add a row.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that dataTables row are automatically highlighted when mouse hovers over it.  And then the highlight will go away if the mouse moves out that row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [`.row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) function will return the `datatable` object, and so will the [`.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) function. Thus, `rowAdded` is not the new row you added.

You could add `.node()` to the end of it to get the added row:

```
var rowAdded = analysisTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false).node();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc : http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add(), you have to use the .node function to get the created node :

```
var rowAdded = analysisTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false).node();
```

Answer (score 0):

The draw method that you call in your code here:

> var rowAdded = analysisTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false);

does not return the added row.  Instead it returns the datatable object.

You need to get the node that was added by calling the **node()** method on the datatable.
Your code should look more like this to return the row:

```
var rowAdded = analysisTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false).node();
$(rowAdded).addClass('selected');
```

RE: [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())